# return csv file in response with only headers in it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I need to create an rest api in django which would return a csv file  which contains headers only inside it , and also file is created during run time. Here is my code, don't know why it is not sending file, ideally this function should return csv file which would have headers as filenames.

```
def get_template():

    fieldnames = ['id, rate_plan_name, test_cd, test_name, price, 
                  is_package, is_deleted']
    with open('templates.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        wtr = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        wtr.writerow(fieldnames)

        response = HttpResponse('templates.csv', content_type='application/x-download')
        filename = "template_%s.csv" % (datetime.utcnow())
        content = "attachment; filename='%s'" % filename
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (use StreamingHttpResponse):

```
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
# this is simplified - you can use csv.reader/writer here;

# your views definition go here


csv_headers = 'id,reate_plan_name, ...'
buffer = StringIO()
buffer.write(csv_headers)
response = StreamingHttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), content_type="text/csv")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.csv"'
return response
```

Happy codding.